# Open source alternative to Tableau?

Tags: open-source, charts, analytics

I am looking for an interactive exploratory tool to embed in a commercial application.
I am looking for a commercial-friendly licensed open source alternative to the wonderful Tableau system

Comment: Irony: first result on Google, exactly matches what I want to find out. Closed as not constructive.

Comment: There is this D3 Chart builder - Tableau like and web based https://my.infocaptor.com/free_data_visualization.php

Comment: Check out this [similar question over at the SE statistics and data analysis site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44204/does-anyone-know-any-good-open-source-software-for-visualizing-data-from-databas)

Comment: @Irwin true of many promising stack overflow questions these days.

Comment: [Syncfusion Dashboards[(http://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) are an option. Free community license available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build interactive exploratory visualizations in the browser with [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/).

Comment: Have you used both D3 and Tableau, @Jeff? Wondering what the trade offs are. Tableau definitely seems easier to use but much harder to automate.

Comment: @Jeff D3 is really for publishing, whereas Tableau-like tools also have an exploratory component.

Comment: D3 is nothing like Tableau. Tableau isn't nearly as powerful and flexible as D3, and D3 isn't nearly as friendly for beginners as the drag-and-drop Tableau interface, or useful for "exploratory" analysis. They both make charts, but the use-cases are totally different.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/). It's built from open source parts so you should be able to reuse parts of that. There's also [R](http://www.r-project.org/), though that is really more of a statistical programming framework than an ready-to-use exploratory tool.

If you're looking for something that's as easy to use as Tableau though, I'm afraid you won't find any open source solutions.

Comment: Pentaho is awesome, 10x for sharing